# Cordova StatusBar plugin not working

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have searched for hours on this website and others and can't find a solution.

Using [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar) plugin, I need to have the status bar have styleDefault on my home page, and styleLightContent on every other page. Testing with the Xcode simulator, I can set the style globally with the use of `<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value=“default" />`, but when I try to set it to lightcontent with javascript after leaving the home page, it doesn’t work.

For example, in my app.js the following does nothing:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    StatusBar.hide();
}
```

and calling `StatusBar.hide()` or `StatusBar.styleDefault()` when I’m loading another page just breaks it. My text-editor (brackets) suggests the available properties/methods of StatusBar when I’m typing it, but when when testing with a browser it says that StatusBar is undefined.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that the statusbar.js is loaded on the other pages. Test it with the developer tools.

Comment: Which version of Cordova are you using? The docs say you must use 5.0+

Comment: if you navigate to other pages using location.href ="otherpage.html", you have to link cordova.js on that page too